# invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'torecv.jpg' python

Tags: python, file, sockets, runtime-error

I'm writing a client-server live screenshot streaming. My program works for few seconds. I can see live stream from my client but then my program crushs with this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/user-pc/PycharmProjects/TestsFor/Functions‌​/screenshotLive2/ser‌​ver files.py", line 51, in <module> receive_file(filename) File "C:/Users/user-pc/PycharmProjects/TestsFor/Functions‌​/screenshotLive2/ser‌​ver files.py", line 36, in receive_file f = open(file_name, 'wb') IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'torecv.jpg'`

This is really weird because its able to open and close it many times before it crushes. Does anyone understand why?

This is my server:

```
import socket               # Import socket module
import cv2
import struct
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # put socket outside of loop?
    sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 8200))
    sock.listen(1)
    connect, address = sock.accept()
except socket.error:
    print "Socket Error"


def recv_msg():
    # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
    raw_msglen = recvall(4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('L', raw_msglen)[0]
    # Read the message data
    return recvall(msglen)


def recvall(n):
    # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
    data = ''
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = connect.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data += packet
    return data


def receive_file(file_name):
    f = open(file_name, 'wb')
    data = recv_msg()
    f.writelines(data)
    f.close()

while True:
    receive_file(r'torecv.jpg')
    image = cv2.imread(r'torecv.jpg',1)
    cv2.imshow("Live Screen", image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

And this my client:

```
import ImageGrab
import StringIO
import socket
import struct
try:
    connect = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connect.connect(("localhost", 8200))


except socket.error:
    print "Error Socket"


def screen_shot():
    im = ImageGrab.grab()  # take screen shot
    saver = StringIO.StringIO()  # creating string as 'File'
    im.save(saver, "jpeg")  # save the file (not on hard drive)
    binary_string = saver.getvalue()
    saver.close()
    msg = struct.pack('L', len(binary_string)) + binary_string
    return msg


while True:
    connect.sendall(screen_shot())
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your post!

Comment: I added the full error traceback

Comment: It might not be able to open the file as it might be in use OR Its unable to locate the file-path. Try using "wb+" and let us know what happens.

Comment: same error but with wb+

Comment: Can you print the file-path and see what os.path.exists(file-path) returns ?

Comment: It returns `True` even right before the crush

Comment: Try converting `def receive_file(file_name):` to use a `with` statement for your file. This will ensure the file handle is always closed (no need for an explicit `f.close()`

Comment: How about read/write permissions after and before the crash, which OS ?

Comment: @MartinEvans, The `with` statement didn't solve the problem,

Comment: @JaiminAjmeri Sorry, I didn't understand the question

Comment: Which Operating System the scripts are running ?
Can you see the permissions of that file if not the directory in which that file is present.

Comment: I am running `windows` 8 , And I have `full control` permission over the file,

Comment: Can u add some delay before `receive_file(r'torecv.jpg')` and see what happens ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129013/discussion-between-jaimin-ajmeri-and-eyal-s).